# Matlab: read only header line from a .csv-file

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

Assume there's a myfile.csv with variable names in the first row and decimal numbers in the following ones. In Matlab I'd like to read the header line and the decimal numbers separately. So far, I've been doing the following to extract the header line:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.csv');
a = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
b = a{1,1};
fclose(fid);
c = textscan(b,'%s','Delimiter',',');
d = c{1}
```

Then, I use the csvread command to extract the numerical part of the file. But there should be a (much) easier way to do it! First, I don't want to read the whole file (as with `a = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');`) to extract only the first line. Second, it looks wrong to use 7 lines of code to do it - can it be done with less?

I'd be thankful for any constructive suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for line 3. Also, it looks better this way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file with `fopen`, read the header line with `textscan`, read the decimal numbers with `fscanf`, and call `fclose` in the end - only 4 lines in total :) Example input file:

```
Weight,Size,Count
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

Reading of this file:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.csv', 'r');
header = textscan(fid, '%[^,],%[^,],%[^,\r\n]', 1);
data = transpose(fscanf(fid, '%g,%g,%g\n', [3, Inf]));
fclose(fid);

for i = 1 : 3; disp(['"' cell2mat(header{i}) '"']); end;
disp(data);
```

Note that the data read by `fscanf` need to be transposed (I emphasized this by writing `transpose` instead of `'`). The output:

```
"Weight"
"Size"
"Count"
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if I wanted to write the code in a more universal way, such that it can be used for files with different number of variables (instead of 3), without rewriting it each time the number of variables change?

Comment: In that case I would read the header line with `getl` and parse it with `strtok` to get the number of columns, `nc`. After `nc` was determined, the format string of `fscanf` can be assembled using a loop (by concatenating `%g`'s with commas in between), and its last parameter can be set to `[nc, Inf]`. Alternatively, you can read the numbers into a single column (using `[1 Inf]`), and reshape it later (no. of rows: `nr = length(data(:)) / nc;`).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answers!

Answer (score 1):

To extract the first line, you just need

```
fid = fopen('myfile.csv');
a = textscan(fid,'%s',1);
fclose(fid);
```