# Matlab load command

Tags: matlab

I know that to use the load command I need to write:

`blah = load('test.txt')`

My problem is I need to skip the 1st few lines of my test file, i.e. the file is of the form

872  
30  
FR

(below here is data that needs to be put in matrix)

0000.0 0000.0 0000.0 etc... 
0001.0 0000.0 0000.0 etc... 
0002.0 0000.0 0000.0 etc...

So how do I do that?

I also have another file that looks like:

1   (abcdef) 
2   (fedcba) 
3   (edfbac) 
on to 800 or so.

Is it possible load this kind of file in to a matrix? (N.b. I need to be able to look in the matrix to find the certain letter combinations, and then load a file the corresponds to the number associated with the letters).

Comment: Please, take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/254504

Comment: possible duplicate of [Average of values from a column/ Skip lines (textscan)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617405/average-of-values-from-a-column-skip-lines-textscan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this by reading the file in line by line, and deciding how many lines to skip with something simple like what we can see below.

```
fid = fopen('temp.txt','r');
count = 1;
lines2skip = 3;
mat = [];
while ~feof(fid)
    if count <= lines2skip
        count = count+1;
        [~] = fgets(fid); % throw away unwanted line
        continue;
    else
        line = strtrim(fgets(fid));
        mat = [mat;cell2mat(textscan(line,'%f')).'];
        count = count +1;
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, you wouldn't happen to know how to write the lines I don't skip in to a matrix do you?

Comment: They're all the same (of the few I've seen, there's 2400 of them).

872
30
FR (<--Headers)

00000.0 0000.0 0000.0 (on to 872)
00001.0 0000.0 0000.0 etc
00002.0 0000.0 0000.0 etc

Sorry I'm not sure how to enter a line break.

Comment: I can not really tell from here, please edit your question above to include an example of your data.

Comment: yeah sorry it took me a while to respond, I see it. Give me a few minutes and I will update my answer

Comment: Edited to make a matrix

Comment: Cheers for that. Matlab gives me the error that mat is an undefined variable. I've tried to fix this by going p = 1:29, q = 1: 872, mat(p,q) = 0 (and thus create a matrix of zeros I assume), but it doesn't look right, got any more hints?   Also, I posted another question, can you give me some more really good insight? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731851/generating-a-matrix-after-importing-data-from-csv-file-with-fgets-in-matlab  Look at the comments under the question before making an answer. In them I explain the big picture a little better.

Comment: This seems to concatenate the matrix I made to get rid of the undefined variable error, rather than rewrite it, any clues?

Comment: to create a blank matrix simply use the `zeros` command, something like `zeros(29,872)`

Comment: I fixed it ;)

Can you lend a hand with this question? You've been so helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787104/making-a-matrix-of-strings-read-in-from-file-using-feof-function-in-matlab

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `load` is for loading MATLAB data files (*.mat), see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/load.html. For text files, best use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) or [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html).

Comment: +1 textscan example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414300/matlab-read-only-header-line-from-a-csv-file/8414375#8414375

Comment: Ok, so is there a way of reading the array textscan gives me so I can find the value that corresponds to a a certain string? I.e.say I've got
a 1
b 2
c 3

etcetera, how do I get an output of 2 whenever there's a b in the 1st column?