# Generating a matrix after importing data from csv file with fgets in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, fgets

I need to generate a matrix (30x900) of data (for complex analysis) after reading said data from a csv (text) file. 
I can read the data in to matlab using fgets, unfortunately I can't use load as the data has a header. 
The files look like this:

872 
30  
FR

(Data below here needs to be put in to matrix)

0000.0  0000.0  0000.0  
0001.0  0000.0  0000.0  
0002.0  0000.0  0000.0

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you have a reason to use fgets instead of csvread? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html

Comment: I've never heard of csvread until now. Looking at the link you posted, that may not work as some of the files don't contain only numeric values.

Comment: How do you want to handle the non-numeric values? You can't mix numbers and characters in matrices, unfortunately.

Comment: Right, here's the skinny. I've lots of data files (about 2400 files, each a 30x870 matrix). I have some other files that describe what each data file is, ie what experiment. I need matlab to be able to find certain data files, and then load those and do some analysis with them. It needs to find which data file to load by looking at the file Can you shed any light?

Comment: So will csvread work on the data files, using something like fgets to pull the file and experiment names out of the index?

Comment: csvread only appears to give me the 1st line. I need it to give me the data as a matrix, because I need to analyse the column.

Comment: Can you put what your files look like in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use `csvread` instead.

```
filename = 'file.txt';
numberOfLinesInHeader = 3;
M = csvread(filename, numberOfLinesInHeader, 0);
```

Comment: Does it matter that the data isn't separated by commas, just spaces?

Comment: CSV stands for Comma-Separated Values. So that will not work.

Comment: Ah. Wikipedia said it meant character separated values.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at [`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) too. It's a very easy to use and high level function. Here is the *forth syntax*:

```
del = ' '; % Delimiter
nHl = 5; % Number of header lines
dat = importdata('text.txt', del, nHl)
```

Now `dat` is a structure; `dat.data` contains data and header goes in `dat.textdata`.

Comment: I can't get this to work for some reason. I get the incredibly useful error message "Error in importdata (line 10)
dat = importdata('run00001.txt', del, nhl);" <br/>

I'm using the student version of matlab, do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: But what is the error? Can you post the full message? You now have posted the position of the error, not the error itself. Type `help importdata` to make sure if you have the function.

Comment: Here's the full message: Attempt to execute SCRIPT importdata as a function:
C:\Send to Pearce\TXT 580\importdata.m

Error in importdata (line 10)
dat = importdata('run00001.txt', del, nhl);

Comment: So you have an file named `importdata` which is the name of the function you are using as well. Find the mentioned file in error message (`C:\Send to Pearce\TXT 580\importdata.m`) and rename it.