# Making a matrix of strings read in from file using feof function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an index file (called runnumber_odour.txt) that looks like this:

```
run00001.txt   ptol
run00002.txt   cdeg
run00003.txt   adef
run00004.txt   adfg
```

I need some way of loading this in to a matrix in matlab, such that I can search through the second column to find one of those strings, load the corresponding file and do some data analysis with it. (i.e. if I search for "ptol", it should load run00001.txt and analyse the data in that file).

I've tried this:

```
clear; clc ;
% load index file - runnumber_odour.txt
runnumber_odour = fopen('Runnumber_odour.txt','r');
count = 1;
lines2skip = 0;

while ~feof(runnumber_odour)

 runnumber_odourmat = zeros(817,2);
 if count <= lines2skip
     count = count+1;
     [~] = fgets(runnumber_odour); % throw away unwanted line
     continue;
 else
     line = strcat(fgets(runnumber_odour));
     runnumber_odourmat = [runnumber_odourmat ;cell2mat(textscan(line, '%f')).'];
     count = count +1;
   end
end

runnumber_odourmat
```

But that just produces a 817 by 2 matrix of zeros (i.e. not writing to the matrix), but without the line runnumber_odourmat = zeros(817,2); I get the error "undefined function or variable 'runnumber_odourmat'.

I have also tried this with strtrim instead of strcat but that also doesn't work, with the same problem.

So, how do I load that file in to a matrix in matlab?

Answer (score 2):

You can do all of this pretty easily using a Map object so you will not have to do any searching or anything like that. Your second column will be a key to the first column. The code will be as follows

```
clc; close all; clear all;
fid = fopen('fileList.txt','r'); %# open file for reading
count = 1;
content = {};
lines2skip = 0;
fileMap = containers.Map();
while ~feof(fid)
    if count <= lines2skip
        count = count+1;
        [~] = fgets(fid); % throw away unwanted line
    else
        line = strtrim(fgets(fid));
        parts = regexp(line,' ','split');
        if numel(parts) >= 2
            fileMap(parts{2}) = parts{1};
        end
        count = count +1;
    end
end
fclose(fid);

fileName = fileMap('ptol')

% do what you need to do with this filename
```

This will provide for quick access to any element

You can then do what was described in the previous question you had asked, with the answer I provided.

Comment: Thanks for that, it seems to work apart from the last line which gives this error:

Error using containers.Map/subsref
The specified key is not present in this container.

Error in filemaptest (line 28)
fileName = fileMap('ptol')